# URL rewriting is not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to use URL rewriting to a website.I had placed an .htaccess file in the server and turned on rewrite mode on and it seems to be working except one issue that I'm having.
I have two php extension files namely category.php and products.php resp.

Here is my requirement, the category.php should be called when one condition is met and products.php should be called another condition is meet

**.HTACCESS**:

```
RewriteRule ([A-Za-z-_]+) category.php?arg=name
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z-_'']+)/([0-9]+) product.php?arg=name&pid=id
```

So her are my website url 
FOR CATEGORY PAGES

```
http://www.mysite.com/category1
```

FOR PRODUCT PAGES

```
http://www.mysite.com/product-name/101
```

So the problem is with second url rewrite condition i.e product page url.When i put the ur l in browser it goes to 404.Whereas 1 rewrite condition seemed to work.Please help to access the webpage in the above format.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add boundaries to your regex and backreference your captured groupings:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z-_]+)$ category.php?arg=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z-_'']+)/([0-9]+)$ product.php?arg=$1&pid=$2 [L]
```

Comment: You are awesome.It worked for some with little corrections. Initially your rule doesn't work, later I had removed the backslash  that comes before category.php and product.php then it worked as desired. 
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z-_]+)$ /category.php?arg=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z-_'']+)/([0-9]+)$ /product.php?arg=$1&pid=$2 [L] . My another question I have some other pages like about-us.php,contact-us.php,download.php.In this case these pages has similar rule like category, it could possibly redirect to category.Is there a way to overcome this so that I can have no extension for common webpages.

Comment: @Jone if you are routing the same exact way for `about-us.php` etc, then there will be a conflict because `^([A-Za-z-_]+)$` will match it, and it'll all get routed to the first rule that matches. You'll need to prefix it with something unique, like `http://mysite.com/about/something` and `http://mysite.com/contact/something` and `http://mysite.com/download/something`, then the rule's regex would be `^about/([A-Za-z-_]+)$`, `^contact/([A-Za-z-_]+)$`, `^download/([A-Za-z-_]+)$`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem is that in regex's character class hyphen should be either or start or at end otherwise it needs to be escaped (it will represent range otherwise).**

Both of our rules:

```
RewriteRule ([A-Za-z-_]+) category.php?arg=name
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z-_'']+)/([0-9]+) product.php?arg=name&pid=id
```

**are not using correct regex** and will produce wrong results.

Replace your rules with this code:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z_-]+)/?$ /category.php?arg=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z_'-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /product.php?arg=$1&pid=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

**PS:** I have made some more corrections in the rule to handle unexpected situations better.